# Minimize iOS App Size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

After archiving the build, the build size is almost doubled that of the build generated by dragging and dropping .app to iTunes. Why the build size is increased while archiving. Appreciate the suggestions.TY

Comment: Could you please attach some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

The archive includes your debugging symbols .dsym file. Also see this duplicate post and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952939/3729825).

In addition: assets are the issue in our case. You can in most cases remove meta data from your assets, it's a few kb per assets but with big quantities it adds up. Make sure to save assets for web, photoshop does this better than e.g Sketch, and there are tools like [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac).

Answer (score 0):

I have had that very same question. To be honest I am not sure. It might have something to do with the version for each device or the assets. Do not worry about the size. Once the app gets put onto the App Store the file size will change. One of my apps was 45mb on my simulator and once it was released onto the App Store the file size went down to 21mb. I honestly would not worry about file size unless you have a lot of pictures or videos.

The file size will decrease a lot once it is on the App Store. But if you are really concerned about the app size, there is a way to compress some of the code.

[Click here for stackoverflow question that's shows how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321409/reducing-ios-app-file-size)

Congratulations on your app!

Answer (score 0):

The archived version of the app includes all the assets and compiled code. If you are using Bitcode the size will be large as it will include all the slices of the app. However the downloaded size will differ from the archive size.

This question from Apple support pages also explains how you can determine more accurate file sizes for what the app will actually equal on the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html

You might want to have a look into App Thinning to ensure you optimise the size of your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

or here

http://www.imore.com/app-thinning-ios-9-explained

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about the size. As soon as you upload it to the app store, bitcode will do it work which will make the app a lot smaller.