# Difference in build(ipa) size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, nskeyedunarchiver

For my project, after archiving the build, the build size got it shows as 20MB, but when i installed build through iTunes it got increased to 55MB.(iPhone settings > storage > app info). why there is two different behaviors of build.

Answer (score 2):

The build sizes will vary for the archive build and AppStore builds. You can check it in your iTunesConnect>Apps>Activity>Allbuild>Select Version> Select Build Details.
See screenshots attached.
[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: Also go through these answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/32590568/5997339 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11952939/5997339

Comment: What is the difference?  Why it showing more size in device.  Does it gave any impact?